# ajax url is working fine on localhost but giving 404 on server java servlet tomcat hosting server

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

i have completed my application on localhost and working fine but i am 
having problem while uploading to server.

here is my localhost code for ajax and which is running fine.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/Certificates/ViewCertificates",
      dataType: "JSON",
     success: function (data) {
     console.log(data); 
     }
   });

but when am upload to my domain and change url to example

 http://example.com/Certificates/ViewCertificates

  it gives me 404 error on the ajax call. i have tried many solutions that are given on stackoverflow and other platforms but none of them is giving me success. 

here is my web.xml mapping
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ViewCertificates</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controller.ViewCertificates</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ViewCertificates</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ViewCertificates</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

 it will be highly appreciated if anyone can give me hint or a link which i can read to solve this out.
```

Comment: where is the Ajax call running from? is your FE deployed somewhere? in addition, please share your BE controller code

Comment: 404 would seem to indicate that it's not deployed where you think it is. Can you hit the URL directly?